# Encoding accented/dotted characters in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf

I am trying to make a random string generator, that can generate strings of length min <= n <= max. However, I am still confused on encoding characters. I got them to show up on the print line, but it does not show up as the correct length. Is there something I have done in correctly?

my input: a ä æ e i ï o u ü b ḅ d ḍ f v h ḥ k g l ľ m y n ṇ p ṕ r ṛ s j w ẉ x x̣
5
10

```
from random import *
#Class random generator
#@variables list aList,boolean again, int maximum, int minimum
class randomStringGenerator:
    def __init__(this):
        aList = []
        allowed = input("What are the characters that you will allow?\n" +
                        "Please press the chracters you want and leave a space between each character\n, then enter to submit\n" +
                        "e.g. 'a' 'b' 'c'\n ")
        aList = allowed.split(" ")
        minimum = input("What is the minimum number of characters in the string that you want? \n")
        maximum = input("What is the maximum number of characters in the string that you want? \n")
        this.aList = aList
        this.minimum = int(minimum)
        this.maximum = int(maximum)
        again = True
        this.again = again
    #generateRandNum generates a random int from a minimum to b maximum
    #@param this,mini,maxi
    #@return int x the integer that was chosen
    def generateRandNum(this,mini,maxi):
        x = randint(mini,maxi)
        return x
    #generateRandString generates the actual string randomly

    def generateRandString(this):
        ans = ""
        strSize = this.generateRandNum(this.minimum,this.maximum)
        pos = 0
        while(pos < strSize):
            size = len(this.aList)
            idx = this.generateRandNum(0,size - 1)
            char = this.aList[idx]
            ans = ans + char
            pos += 1
            ans.encode('utf-8')
            print(ans)
    def getAgain(this):
        return this.again
    def replay(this):
        x = input("Would you like to generate another string using the same settings? y/n \n")
        if(x == "y"):
            this.generateRandString()
        else:
            y = input("Would you like to generate another string using different settings? y/n \n")
            if(y == "y"):
                new = input("What are the new characters that you will allow? ")
                mini = input("What is the new minimum number of characters? ")
                maxi = input("What is the new maximum number of characters? ")
                this.aList = new.split(" ")
                this.minimum = int(mini)
                this.maximum = int(maxi)
                this.generateRandString()
            else:
                this.again = False
s = randomStringGenerator()
s.generateRandString()
while(s.getAgain()):
    s.replay()
```

Sample output: As you can see, I set the minimum characters to be 5, but only 2 show up, and for some reason multiple print...

```
What are the characters that you will allow?
Please press the chracters you want and leave a space between each character
, then enter to submit
e.g. 'a' 'b' 'c'
 a ä æ e i ï o u ü b ḅ d ḍ f v h ḥ k g l ľ m y n ṇ p ṕ r ṛ s j w ẉ x x̣
What is the minimum number of characters in the string that you want? 
5
What is the maximum number of characters in the string that you want? 
10
o
oḅ
oḅ
oḅ
oḅ
oḅ
oḅ
```

Comment: is it Python2.7 or Python3.x? unicode is the default encoding system for Python3.x, so encoding is less likely to be a problem. For Python2.7, add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in the beginning. If there is non-unicode characters in the script, add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ` to very top of the code.

Comment: Python 3, but for some reason it does not show up correctly in my code unless I use the .encode method

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. The issue of the character limit not being reached is still an issue.

Comment: What's your intention? To me, the code in `generateRandString` just get a random number from 5 to 10, and then generate a string of that length, for which your codes appears to be doing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problem in your code.

1. use `self` instead of `this` in python.
2. add a `if __name__ == "__main__"` to your program
3. use a encoding `encoding: utf-8` to specify the encoding.
4. define the get input operation as a funcion `_prepare()`

The updated code is as below:

```
#encoding:utf-8
from random import *

class randomStringGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.aList = []
        self.again = True
        self._prepare()

    def _prepare(self):
        allowed = input("What are the characters that you will allow?\n"
                        "Please press the chracters you want and leave a space between each character\n, then enter to submit\n"
                        "e.g. 'a' 'b' 'c'\n")
        aList = allowed.split(" ")
        minimum = input("What is the minimum number of characters in the string that you want? \n")
        maximum = input("What is the maximum number of characters in the string that you want? \n")
        self.aList = aList
        self.minimum = int(minimum)
        self.maximum = int(maximum)

    def generateRandNum(self, mini, maxi):
        x = randint(mini,maxi)
        return x

    def generateRandString(self):
        ans = u""
        strSize = self.generateRandNum(self.minimum, self.maximum)
        pos = 0
        while(pos < strSize):
            size = len(self.aList)
            idx = self.generateRandNum(0, size - 1)
            char = self.aList[idx]
            ans = ans + char
            pos += 1
            ans.encode('utf-8')
        return ans

    def getAgain(self):
        return self.again

    def replay(self):
        x = input("Would you like to generate another string using the same settings? y/n \n")
        if(x == "y"):
            return self.generateRandString()
        else:
            y = input("Would you like to generate another string using different settings? y/n \n")
            if(y == "y"):
                self._prepare()
                return self.generateRandString()
            else:
                self.again = False
                return ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = randomStringGenerator()
    print (s.generateRandString())
    while(s.getAgain()):
        print (s.replay())
```

Output as this:

```
python3 str_1.py 
What are the characters that you will allow?
Please press the chracters you want and leave a space between each character
, then enter to submit
e.g. 'a' 'b' 'c'
a ä æ e i ï o u ü b ḅ d ḍ f v h ḥ k g l ľ m y n ṇ p ṕ r ṛ s j w ẉ x x̣
What is the minimum number of characters in the string that you want? 
5
What is the maximum number of characters in the string that you want? 
10
bpjwdsndv
Would you like to generate another string using the same settings? y/n 
y
radsṛreyrx
Would you like to generate another string using the same settings? y/n 
n
Would you like to generate another string using different settings? y/n 
y
What are the characters that you will allow?
Please press the chracters you want and leave a space between each character
, then enter to submit
e.g. 'a' 'b' 'c'
a ä æ e i ï o u ü b ḅ d ḍ f v h ḥ k g l ľ m y n ṇ p ṕ r ṛ s j w ẉ x x̣
What is the minimum number of characters in the string that you want? 
5
What is the maximum number of characters in the string that you want? 
8
dnṛnhṛv
Would you like to generate another string using the same settings? y/n 
n
Would you like to generate another string using different settings? y/n 
n
```

Comment: In Python3, there is no raw_input

Comment: Thank you! Switching between Java and Python confuses me sometimes, and I accidentally started using "this" instead of "self".